# Catch all route EXCEPT for /login

Tags: node.js, express

I am currently writing an API which will require a user to pass an authentication token in the header of each request.  Now I know I can create a catchall route say

```
app.get('/*', function(req,res){

});
```

but I was wondering how do I make it so that it excludes certain routes such as `/login` or `/`?

Comment: E.g Require authentication on all routes *except* **/login** and **/register**. (Since people are wondering why you asked this question)

Answer (score 162, accepted):

I'm not sure what you want to happen when a user accesses `/login` or `/`, but you can create separate routes for those; if you declare them before the catch-all, they get first dibs at handling the incoming requests:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  ...
});

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This would only work for "GET"'s right? For some reason I can't get this answer to work with `app.use` (to include the other methods).

Comment: @SSHThis I think that with the most recent version of Express (v4), `app.use('*', ...)` should work as well. But using [`app.all('*', ...)`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.all) is preferable in this case.

Comment: @JulienMartin just tested, looks like it works as expected with Express v4.16.3

Comment: `app.use` adds middleware, which by design mostly pass on the request to the next handler in the chain (using extra argument `next`).

Answer (score 59):

You can always place catch-all route after the ones you want to exclude (see [robertklep](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19313369/1202461) answer).

But sometimes you simply don't want to care about the order of your routes. In this case you still can do what you want:

```
app.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.url === '/' || req.url === '/login') return next();
  ...
});
```

Comment: .get('*', function(req, res, next).

Comment: @iLoveUnicorns thanx! Why didn't you just edit my post?

Comment: If the other rules are Before that one, is it needed to call next?

Comment: @Sandburg middleware should either call `next()` to pass execution to the next middleware, or send some response to finish processing the request. Otherwise request will hang. If the last middleware in the stack called `next()` then express will send the default "404 Not Found" response. Instead of calling `next()` you could, for example, call `res.status(400).end()` to finish request processing with a "400 Bad Request" response.

Answer (score 30):

If you want to validate credentials or authenticity in every request you should use Express Routing feature "all", you can use it like this:

```
app.all('/api/*', function(req, res, next){
    console.log('General Validations');
    next();
});
```

You could place it before any Routing stuff.

Note that in this case I used "/api/*" as path, you can use "/*" you it fits your needs.

Hope it is not too late to help somebody here.

Answer (score 12):

Another way to make a catch-all route handler is this:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
  //... login page
});
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  //...index page
});
app.get('/:pageCalled', function(req, res) {
  console.log('retrieving page: ' + req.params.pageCalled);
  //... mypage.html
});
```

This works exactly like robertklep's (accepted) answer, but it gives you more information about what the user actually requested.  You now have a slug `req.params.pageCalled` to represent whatever page is being requested and can direct the user to the appropriate page if you have several different ones.

One gotchya to watch out for (thx @agmin) with this approach, `/:pageCalled` will only catch routes with a single `/`, so you will not get `/route/1`, etc.  Use additional slugs like `/:pageCalled/:subPageCalled` for more pages (thx @softcode)

Comment: BETTER? Really? Don't you thing the circumstances dictate the definition? ;-)
Unrelated: People downvoting without leaving a comment: How rude!

Comment: there's a huge gotchya with this approach, `/:pageCalled` will only catch routes with a single `/`, so you will not get `/route/1` etc.

Comment: Also, if you do not surround it in a try/catch you will get an error if that page doesn't exist.

Comment: @agmin so would the solution not be to simply add `/:pageCalled/:subPageCalled` etc. ?

Answer (score 6):

**Negative lookahead regex**

Maybe this will come handy at times:

```
const app = require('express')()
app.get(/^\/(?!login\/?$)/, (req, res) => { res.send('general') })
app.get('*',                (req, res) => { res.send('special') })
app.listen(3000)
```

With this, you would get:

```
/           general
/asdf       general
/login      special
/login/     special
/login/asdf general
/loginasdf  general
```

Or if you also want `/login/asdf` to be `special`:

```
app.get(/^\/(?!login($|\/.*))/, (req, res) => { res.send('general') })
```

In particular, when I Googled here I was thinking about the case of serving static frontend files on the same server that does the API for a SPA:

```
const apiPath = '/api';
const buildDir = path.join(__dirname, 'frontend', 'build');

// Serve static files like /index.html, /main.css and /main.js
app.use(express.static(buildDir));
// For every other path not under /api/*, serve /index.html
app.get(new RegExp('^(?!' + config.apiPath + '(/|$))'), function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(buildDir, 'index.html'));
});

// Setup some actions that don't need to be done for the static files like auth.
// The negative lookahead above allows those to be skipped.
// ...

// And now attach all the /api/* paths which were skipped above.
app.get(apiPath, function (req, res) { res.send('base'); });
app.get(apiPath, function (req, res) { res.send('users'); });

// And now a 404 catch all.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.status(404).send('error: 404 Not Found ' + req.path)
})

// And now for any exception.
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(err.stack)
  res.status(500).send('error: 500 Internal Server Error')
});

app.listen(3000)
```

Tested on express@4.17.1, Node.js v14.17.0.

Comment: Thanks! I was surprised that on many threads nobody suggested regex.

This is what worked for me `/^(?!\/login).+/`

With your example `/^\/(?!login\/?$)/` for some reason it enters the route

Comment: @LobsterMan it depends on what you want for `/login/asdf` I guess. Also you likely want instead `/^\/(?!login($|\/.*))/` otherwise you will catch `/loginasdf`. I added a bit more to the answer.