# Express app to serve index.html at all routes except one sub route

Tags: express

I've built a react/webpack app with a public directory `dist` that contains `index.html` and `bundle.js`.  `index.html` links to the bundle with `<script src="./bundle.js />` and I want to serve `index.html` up for all routes (as react-router handles the routing).  However for `/demos/:name`, when `name` has a value I want to send a static file.  For example, while `/demos` renderings as react component (the server sends index.html), `/demos/one` would be interpreted by my server as requesting `/demos/one.html` from the server.  So far I've attempted that like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get("demos", (req,res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html")
})

app.get("demos/:name", (req,res) => {
    const { name } = req.params
    res.sendFile(__dirname + `./demos/${name}.html`);

})

app.use("*", express.static('dist'));

var server = app.listen(8080, function () {
   var {host, port} = server.address()
   console.log(`listening at http://${host}:${port}`)
})
```

However, I keep getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` in the browser console.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19313016/catch-all-route-except-for-login Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("demos/:name", (req,res) => {
  const { name } = req.params
  res.sendFile(__dirname + `./demos/${name}.html`);
})
app.get("*", (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/dist/index.html")
})
```